How to select a type for a method based on the generic type provided in the class in TypeScript?
I have the following class:
class Processor<TReq, TRes> {
    constructor(
        private handler: (input: TReq) => TRes
    ) {}

    public handleRequest(input: TReq): TRes {
       ...
       const res = this.handler(input);
       ...
    }
}

In this design, I can do this:
const myProcessor = new Processor<string, string>(
    (input: string) => `Hello ${input}`
);
myProcessor.handleRequest('Hello');

My issue is that I want to be able to pass never to TReq, and when that happens, I would like handleRequest to be of type () => TRes, and handler as well:
const myProcessor = new Processor<never, string>(
    () => 'Hi'
);
myProcessor.handleRequest();

How can I achieve this?

I think the closest you can get is the following

You need to define generic constraint for TReq
You need to make handleRequst argument optional

class Processor<TReq, TRes> {
  private handler: [TReq] extends [never] ? () => TRes : (input: TReq) => TRes;

  constructor(
    handler: [TReq] extends [never] ? () => TRes : (input: TReq) => TRes,
  ) {
    this.handler = handler;
  }

  public handleRequest(): TReq extends never ? TRes : never;
  public handleRequest(input: TReq): TReq extends never ? never : TRes;
  public handleRequest(input?: TReq): TRes {
    const res =
      typeof input === 'undefined'
        ? (this.handler as () => TRes)()
        : (this.handler as (input: TReq) => TRes)(input);
    return res;
  }
}

upd: added handleRequest overloads with generic constraint as suggested in comments. Still not perfect, but i'm afraid this is the best you can get from TS

This code doesn't compile playground

Sorry about that! edited. You can try new version

Now it does compile, but in handleRequest you are checking about if input is undefined, not the type of TReq, allowing this scenario

scenario

i think the best you can get from TS is by providing constrained method overloads
public handleRequest(): TReq extends never ? TRes : never;
public handleRequest(input: TReq): TReq extends never ? never : TRes;

Apologies for the dummy question, what are the square brackets around the type? In the definition of handler, you use square brackets in the conditional type definition. Why?

Actually it is a great question! There is a something called distributive conditional Types, you can read about it in the docs.
And here is related question with a good answer

Yeah I think that constrained method overloads is the way to go, it's kinda tricky to implement though (I can't implement it in the playground). I think it should be the answer

I am experiencing the same difficulty... I am trying to implement it and see how it goes

It is indeed not an easy problem to solve, but this is not a bad solution! I will wait a little longer to mark this answer just to see if other answers come up. For now you get a well deserved upvote :) Thanks for your time!

cool, slightly improved the answer with regards of our discussion
